# How to recognize repeated movement patterns of mouse behavior using OpenCV?

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have a situation where I have collected mouse movement points from a website. I have a series of (x, y)-points, and I need to detect different repeated patterns of mouse movement from this data. For example, mouse moving very slowly, mouse moving very fast toward a direction and then stopping for a while, mouse scrolling, etc.

Is there a way to do that with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), or maybe some other Library?

P.S. Please keep in mind, that I am a beginner in this kind of stuff.

Comment: Do you have a particular language in mind? Python, Matlab, R? What are your programming skills? Because this is mostly some basic signal processing stuff (i.e., computing acceleration, velocity, etc.) so that you don't necessarily need a complete SDK.